# App freezes if secure text entry is enables on text field Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, xcode8

Im running into a strange issue. I have a few text fields in a view and if secure text entry is enabled for an of them my app freezes when I run it.

Has anybody encountered this issue/know the fix for it? I have done a but of research and one possibility could be a memory leak. Other than that I can't seem to find any information on this. Any help is much appreciated!

All code that acts on my text fields:

Sets up UI:

```
self.passwordTextField.delegate = self
passwordTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1
passwordTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
passwordTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
passwordTextField.returnKeyType = .done
```

Adds observer:

```
usernameTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
passwordTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
```

Observer function:

```
func textFieldDidChange() {
    if usernameTextField.text == "" || passwordTextField.text == "" {
        loginButtonInactive()
    } else {
        loginButtonActive()
    }
}
```

Change login button appearance:

```
func loginButtonActive() {
    logInButton.isEnabled = true
    logInButton.layer.borderWidth = 0
    logInButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    logInButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
}

func loginButtonInactive() {
    logInButton.isEnabled = false
    logInButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
    logInButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    logInButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    logInButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.lightGray, for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Hmm this sounds familiar, for me I only had issues on the simulator, it did not completely freeze, but the simulator was extremely slow on giving a textfield focus. But it ran perfectly on device. How does it work no device vs simulator?

Comment: The behavior is the same in the simulator and on device. A complete freeze.

Comment: can you post some code? :)

Comment: I posted the code that acts on "passwordTextField" which i the problem text field as I want secure text entry enabled for this field. I don't think it will be of any help but maybe I missed something.

Comment: Also can you post the code for the methods you are calling, loginButtonActive and inactice

Comment: Yup! Updated the question!

Comment: have you tried adding a print in textFieldDidChange? does it get called?

Comment: I haven't added a print but I know it gets called because the login button appearance changes.

Comment: Have you tried Time profiler to see what is blocking the app?

Comment: Hmm I'm not familiar with Time profiler... I'll check it out and eat back to you!

Comment: It happened to me as well. When I tap on the textField, the keyboard won't show up, I can't do anything...But in my case, after maybe 5 seconds, everything was fine again. And if I lauch my app directly from device/simulator, instead of build and run from Xcode, the issue disappeared...

Comment: So I ran the app from Xcode and let it sit frozen for a few minutes, after a while it crashed and in the console I received a message from debugger: terminated due to memory issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. It had to do with this this function:

```
func textFieldDidChange() {
    if usernameTextField.text == "" || passwordTextField.text == "" {
        loginButtonInactive()
    } else {
        loginButtonActive()
    }
}
```

I changed it to this:

```
 func textFieldDidChange() {
    if (usernameTextField.text?.characters.count == 0) || (passwordTextField.text?.characters.count == 0) {
        loginButtonInactive()
    } else {
        loginButtonActive()
    }
}
```

I am not sure why the first function caused the issue as it worked fine in previous projects but the new function works well and fixed the issue!